# How can I edit my OpenShift php.ini and change the default socket to OPENSHIFT_MYSQL_DB_SOCKET

Tags: php, mysql, openshift

How can I edit my php.ini and change the default socket to OPENSHIFT_MYSQL_DB_SOCKET?

I suppose a second question is why doesn't it match in the first place?

when I have my php program open the DB I get this error

```
Message: mysql_connect(): Can't connect to local MySQL server through socket '/var/lib/mysql/mysql.sock' (2)
```

OpenShift MySQL socket env var is as follows:

```
OPENSHIFT_MYSQL_DB_SOCKET=/var/lib/openshift/517ab6855973cab1e200003d//mysql-5.1/socket/mysql.sock
```

Same config/code works find on my local system :-(

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This does the trick in the CodeIgniter file (../application/config/database.php).

```
$openshiftsocket = getenv('OPENSHIFT_MYSQL_DB_SOCKET');
//echo "OpenShift socket is [$openshiftsocket]";

if (isset($openshiftsocket)) {
   echo 'foo';
   ini_set('mysql.default_socket', $openshiftsocket);
}
```